# ALB Timeout when Using Lambda to serve S3-hosted React app through an ALB without cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-security-group, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm trying to access a React app using an AWS Application Load Balancer (internet facing) whose files are hosted in s3 through a lambda. The basic idea is that when the user visits the ALB DNS name (e.g., https://albdnsname or http://albdnsname) the lambda target group triggers the node.js lambda that in turn gets the files from s3.

When I test the lambda through the console, I can see that the lambda is working and is returning the html content in s3. However, when I try to access the app through the ALB DNS name, the ALB times out and nothing is rendered. Here is what I've tried thus far.

1. *Verified the Lambda works:* Again, I've verified the lambda works in the console and is reaching the s3 bucket where the the static files are.
2. *Modified IAM role (attached various permissions):* I've attached AmazonS3FullAccess, AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole, and AmazonS3ObjectLambdaExecutionRolePolicy to the same role and redeployed the lambda.
3. *Tested various configs for security groups with the ALB:* I've created two listeners on the ALB, one is http (80), and the other is https (443). The security group for both just have two inbounds (80 and 443), nothing else. I've also tried attaching a self-signed cert to the https listener to test but the timeout still happens.
4. *Increased timeout of lambda:* I've heard there's a 15 minute limit. At any rate, I've increased this to see if that was issue but that hasn't made a difference.

Is there anyone who can give insight as to anything else to try to resolve this such as further policies to attach, etc., and/or anything related to the security group(s) that I'm missing?

Answer (score -1):

I needed to modify the default VPC in my current env to include internet gateway and a few other resources such as route table. The permissions were and lambda were not the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).